# How to read JSON data from SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, json

I want to read Json data from SQL Server 2012, I know that it will support read Json data in SQL Server 2016, but I need a workaround way to read it now.

I have a column `Text` with this Json code:

```
{"en": "Green", "ar": "أخضر"}
```

I want a procedure or function to give it language prefix and return to me the value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are looking for a generic SQL Server JSON to Table and Table to JSON in SQL Server 2012, this [article](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/) provides a `parseJSON` and a `dbo.ToJSON` function. Using this code, you can run the following code:

```
select * from dbo.parseJSON('  
    {
        "en": "Green",
        "ar": "أخضر"
    }
')
```

this query will return

```
element_id | sequenceNo | parent_Id | Object_ID | Name | StringValue | ValueType
-----------+------------+-----------+-----------+------+-------------+-----------
1          | 0          | 1         | NULL      | en   | Green       | string
2          | 0          | 1         | NULL      | ar   | أخضر        | string
3          | 1          | NULL      | 1         | -    |             | object
```

If one of your columns in a table is a JSON document, you can use a `CROSS APPLY`:

```
create table dbo.test(ID int identity(1,1) , json varchar(max))

insert into dbo.test (json)
select '  
    {
        "en": "Green",
        "es": "Verde"
    }
'

insert into dbo.test (json)
select '  
    {
        "en": "Red",
        "es": "Rojo"
    }


select * from dbo.test t
cross apply (select * from dbo.parseJSON(json)) details
```

This will return the following output:

[image]

Comment: thank you :)
I don't want function that have Json string and return me table ,  I want something more simple .
example
function ( lang_prefix){
select [Text] from MyTable
..... here code to return for example 'Green' if  lang_prefix is 'en'}

Comment: If one of the columns of a table has a string value that is JSON . What do I do?

Comment: @KevinBurton, I have updated my answer to show an example when a table has a string value that is JSON